# Existence of a global solution to a matrix Riccati differential equation - indefinite & constant terms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control

Consider the symmetric matrix Riccati differential equation : 
$$
P'(t) = Q + X^\intercal P(t) +  P(t) X +  P(t)UP(t)
$$
Where everything is symmetric and the coefficients are constant (independent of time). The quadratic term U and the term Q are not definite, instead have a mix of positive and negative eigenvalues (say half half), in different bases.

If it can help, U can be written as :
$$
U = -U_1+\gamma U_2
$$
where $U_1$ is symmetric singular and $U_2$ symmetric semidefinite positive.
Is it possible to tackle the issue of finding conditions for boundedness of P ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer does not give a complete answer, but hopefully does help you gain some insights. Namely, it is possible to use a coordinate transformation in which the dynamics is linear, which might be easier to analyse. Namely, if $\bar{P}$ is a stationary solution to

$$
P'(t) = Q + X^\top P(t) +  P(t)\,X +  P(t)\,U\,P(t), \tag{1}
$$

so

$$
Q + X^\top \bar{P} +  \bar{P}\,X +  \bar{P}\,U\,\bar{P} = 0, \tag{2}
$$

then the transformed coordinates can be obtained using $P(t) = \bar{P} + Y^{-1}(t)$, which is equivalent to

$$
Y(t) = (P(t) - \bar{P})^{-1}. \tag{4}
$$

By using $(2)$ the dynamics of $Y(t)$ can be shown to simplify to

$$
Y'(t) = -\left(U + Y(t)\,(X^\top + \bar{P}\,U) + (X + U\,\bar{P})\,Y(t)\right). \tag{5}
$$

By using [vectorization and the Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) this can be written as the following system of linear first order ordinary differential equations in $x(t) = \text{vec}(Y(t))$

$$
x'(t) = M\,x(t) - \text{vec}(U), \tag{6}
$$

$$
M = -\left((X + U\,\bar{P}^\top) \otimes I + I \otimes (X + U\,\bar{P})\right), \tag{7}
$$

with $I$ the identity matrix of the same size as $P(t)$.

---

Solutions to $(2)$ can be found using the eigendecomposition of the [following matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation#Solution)

$$
Z =
\begin{bmatrix}
X & U \\ -Q & -X^\top
\end{bmatrix} = V\,\Lambda\,V^{-1}, \tag{8}
$$

with $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $Z$ and $V$ containing the corresponding eigenvectors. By defining $W$ as a matrix constructed from any selection of half of the columns of $V$, with

$$
W = 
\begin{bmatrix}
W_1 \\ W_2
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{9}
$$

where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are of the same size as $P(t)$. Then a solution to $(2)$ can be found using

$$
\bar{P} = W_2\,W_1^{-1}. \tag{10}
$$

It can be noted that $V$ always has an even number of columns because the dimensions of $(8)$ are double that of $P(t)$.

---

In order for $P(t)$ to remain bounded requires that $Y(t)$ remains nonsingular, which I don't think can be shown easily, but the fact that it has linear dynamics hopefully makes it easier. Two things can be noted that if $M$ is Hurwitz $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = M^{-1}\,\text{vec}(U)$ or if $M$ has at least one eigenvalue with positive real part $\lim_{t\to\infty} \|x(t)\| \to \infty$ for almost all initial condition with $x(t)$ dominated by the eigenmode of $M$ with the eigenvalue which has the largest positive real part. If transforming $M^{-1}\,\text{vec}(U)$ or the eigenvector of the dominant mode back into a square matrix is nonsingular implies that $\lim_{t\to\infty} Y^{-1}(t)$ should remain bounded. If this isn't the case then $\lim_{t\to\infty} P(t)$ should become unbounded. However, I am not sure this is a sufficient condition and there are probably a couple caveats, such as when there are multiple eigenvalues which have equal largest positive real part.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. With this method I succeeded in finding an explicit solution to a 1D version of my equation.
It is much more complicated in the matrix version, unless you have numerical matrices. 
My goal is not to find an explicit solution but rather to prove existence.
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again, I am trying to apply the method for a simplified version of the problem in matrix form. I succeed in finding then Eigenvectors of Z and obtain a (very complicated) matrix that supposedly is a stationary solution of the Riccati. However it is close to impossible to verify explicitely that it is in fact a stationary solution. Is there a theorem somewhere that states that if one obtains such a matrix, then it is in fact a stationary solution ?

Comment: @FayçalDrissi I couldn't quickly find a source for a theorem, but it can be shown by using that the algebraic Riccati equation from $(2)$ can also be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}\bar{P}&-I\end{bmatrix}Z\begin{bmatrix}I\\ \bar{P}\end{bmatrix}=0.\tag{11}$$By using $(9)$, $(10)$ and the definition of $W$ it follows that $$\begin{bmatrix}I\\ \bar{P}\end{bmatrix}=W\,(I_2\otimes W_1^{-1}),\ Z\,W=W\,\Lambda$$ with $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix whose values correspond to the eigenvalues of $Z$ associated with the eigenvectors in $W$.

Comment: So, the left hand side of $(11)$ can also be written as$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}W_2W_1^{-1}&-I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}W_1\\ W_2\end{bmatrix}}_0\Lambda\,(I_2\otimes W_1^{-1})$$

Comment: It is in fact a good way to verify that $W$ is in fact a solution to the $ARE$. Thank you very much. The real difficulty is then to find the eigenvalues of $Z$ and corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Your method worked for two "simpler" versions of my problem, but it is mainly because the form of $Z$ made it possible to derive eigenvalues.